# How can I center a ComboBox's content vertically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

For example, notice how the text isn't quite in the vertical center of the ComboBox.

[image]

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="_24HoursBook.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="350" MinHeight="450" MinWidth="350">


    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Source="Image/topBarBg.png" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">            
            <TextBlock Text="Platform" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       FontFamily="Georgia"
                       FontSize="15" 
                       Margin="10"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPlatform" 
                      Margin="10"
                      FontFamily="Georgia"
                      FontSize="15"
                      MinHeight="30"
                      MinWidth="140"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem>All Platforms</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Playstation 3</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>XBox 360</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Wii</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>PSP</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>DS</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>            
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Image/about.png" 
               Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0 0 10 0"    />

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Background="#343434">

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Add `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` to your combobox.

Comment: i want to show the list items of combobox horizontally center

Answer (score 6):

You have to play with it, but if I had to guess:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPlatform" 
                  Margin="10"
                  FontFamily="Georgia"
                  FontSize="15"
                  MinHeight="30"
                  MinWidth="140"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
```

Try changing the `MinHeight="30"` to a smaller number.  It might be you are making the box bigger than the text.  The text is centered on the line but the box is bigger.

Comment: Ok, the combobox is centered vertically, I agree. But I want to center the content within the combobox as well.

Comment: Setting the vertical alignment to center of a ComboBoxItem does nothing as well.

Comment: @Sergio VerticalContentAlignment

Answer (score 5):

If I copy and paste your code, the text is vertically aligned in the center of the ComboBox for me. Are you sure you don't have a Style or Template set up in your application that is applying to your controls and making this happen?

EDIT: Nevermind. I actually had a style set up in my application:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

So when i copied and pasted your code in, it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

you can change the vertical/horizontal alignment as so:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPlatform" Margin="10" FontFamily="Georgia" FontSize="15"
                  MinHeight="30" MinWidth="140"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. This would make your answer more useful in the long run.